When I start a simulation an object spawns with an offset
I am working with an AR project rn. It detects an image and as an overlay spawns a cube ( just to test if it's working ), but when i started testing I found out that the cube is spawning with an offset. Can someone explain how to fix this problem? Block with a texture AR Session Origin settings The photo of the problem
And my anchor script:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;

public class ARObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    private ARRaycastManager raycastManager;
    private ARAnchorManager anchorManager;
    private List<ARRaycastHit> hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();

    void Start()
    {
        raycastManager = FindObjectOfType<ARRaycastManager>();
        anchorManager = FindObjectOfType<ARAnchorManager>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                if (raycastManager.Raycast(touch.position, hits, TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
                {
                    Pose hitPose = hits[0].pose;
                    GameObject spawnedObject = Instantiate(prefab, hitPose.position, hitPose.rotation);
                    ARAnchor anchor = anchorManager.AddAnchor(new Pose(hitPose.position, Quaternion.identity));
                    if (anchor != null)
                    {
                        spawnedObject.transform.SetParent(anchor.transform);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Failed to create anchor.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


How could I make a cube spawn DIRECTLY on the image? Without an offset

well your block isnt arguably a prefab, but, id guess its treating its position of 0,0,3, as the origin, so, its instantiating it position+0,0,3 .. yes?

You should be getting NullRef if the images are correct. ARObjectSpawner doesn't have a prefab connected in your image of ARSessionOrigin. OTOH, your ARTrackedImageManager does and I know that if the prefab has a non-zero position, it will act as an offset relative to the tracked image's position, when spawned. As for ARObjectSpawner, you instantiate using the hitPose.position. Whatever this position is, it's in world space. But then you SetParent to your anchor, without setting the world position stays parameter. So when you parent, whatever position it had before, will now act as an offset relative to the parent. If I spawn an object at 3,0,0 world space and parent it to another object at 0,0,3, the child will be at 3,0,0 relative to the parent. So 3,0,3 world space. In both cases, you have offsets.
